Loadrunner Analysis shows zero response time
After fetching the LR analysis report it shows 0 sec response times (avg,min,max,std dev,90th percentile) for some transactions. Please note that the test was executed for web application and Web Http protocol was used. Can someone please explain in what case does this occur and how to prevent it?
When executed a script in VuGen it showed response times correctly for the transactions however when ran it in load  same transactions showed zero response times. Please note that the report was extracted with complete data.

Check your version numbers for controller and load generator down to the version Major.minor(patch) level.   Having mismatched versions can (and does) result in odd timing record reports - Even negative response times have occurred in the past in such cases.
